# Transpose DataFrame in Pandas while preserving Index column

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe, transpose

The problem is, when I transpose the DataFrame, the header of the transposed DataFrame becomes the Index numerical values and not the values in the "id" column. See below original data for examples:

**Original data that I wanted to transpose (but keep the 0,1,2,... Index intact and change "id" to "id2" in final transposed DataFrame)**.
[image]
**DataFrame after I transpose, notice the headers are the Index values and NOT the "id" values (which is what I was expecting and needed)** 
[image]

***Logic Flow***

First this helped to get rid of the numerical index that got placed as the header: [How to stop Pandas adding time to column title after transposing a datetime index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520033/how-to-stop-pandas-adding-time-to-column-title-after-transposing-a-datetime-inde)

Then this helped to get rid of the index numbers as the header, but now "id" and "index" got shuffled around: [Reassigning index in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763800/reassigning-index-in-pandas-dataframe) & [Reassigning index in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763800/reassigning-index-in-pandas-dataframe)

[image]

But now my id and index values got shuffled for some reason.

**How can I fix this so the columns are [id2,600mpe, au565...]?**

**How can I do this more efficiently?**

Here's my code:

```
DF = pd.read_table(data,sep="\t",index_col = [0]).transpose() #Add index_col = [0] to not have index values as own row during transposition
m, n = DF.shape
DF.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
DF.head()
```

This didn't help much: [Add indexed column to DataFrame with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762935/add-indexed-column-to-dataframe-with-pandas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your example, what seems to happen to you is that you `transpose` takes your actual index (the 0...n sequence as column headers. First, if you then want to preserve the numerical index, you can store that as `id2`.

```
DF['id2'] = DF.index
```

Now if you want  `id` to be the column headers then you must set that as an index, overriding the default one:

```
DF.set_index('id',inplace=True)
DF.T
```

I don't have your data reproduced, but this should give you the values of `id` across columns.